# A open/close child component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a view details button in my react app which opens a child "card" component and has a close button

```
                <div id="Card1" className='card d-none' >
                    <span className="close" onClick={this.CloseClick} >&times;</span>
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: do you want to create a modal component? Could you send more code of your application?

Comment: What is your issue? Is that the only code you have? Its not clear where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use conditional rendering. Try something like following:

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     showCard: false,
   };
   this.toggleCard = this.toggleCard.bind(this);
  }
  toggleCard(){
    const show = this.state.showCard
    this.setState({showCard: !show});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleCard}>Toggle card</button>
       {this.state.showCard &&
         <div id="Card1" className='card d-none' >
                  <span className="close" onClick={this.CloseClick} >&times;</span>
                  <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
         </div> 
       }
      </div>
     );
   }
}
```

Of course code is not ideal, you will need to edit it according to your needs. Also, your close button will implement something similar to my `toggleCard` method.